# Oracle: What's the problem with this join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

I can't get this Join to work in Oracle. Can't figure it out, why is it?

```
SELECT E."ci", E."nombre"
FROM EMPLEADO E
WHERE E."ci" IN (SELECT E."cisupervisor" FROM EMPLEADO E);


INNER JOIN empleado ON "ci"= T."ciempleado"

SELECT E."nombre",E."apellido",P."nombreproy"
FROM EMPLEADO E, PROYECTO P
WHERE E."cisupervisor" IN (SELECT E."ci"
FROM EMPLEADO E, PROYECTO P, TRABAJAEN T
WHERE E."sexo"='F' AND E."ci"=T."ciempleado" AND T."horas">60 AND T."codproy"=P."codproy" AND P."fechaini"=2010
);
```

Comment: Is that one single query? It looks like a mess, esp with the ; on line 3

Comment: What are the errors that your getting?

Comment: Individually, lines 1-3 are valid, and the last 6 lines are valid as well, as another query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cyberwiki correctly noted, you are basically trying to join two individual queries.

The first one ends at line 3 because it's terminated with a semicolon.

This part:

```
INNER JOIN empleado ON "ci"= T."ciempleado"
```

doesn't work on it's own since you need a `where` clause after your join if you want more conditions.

Everything after this part is another query that executes well on its own.

You can try [this online validator](http://developer.mimer.se/validator/) and you'll see that lines 1-3 and everything after `inner join` are valid SQL 2003 statements, although your entire query isn't.

It seems to me you need to work a bit more on understanding how joins work. You can't just join two individual queries.

I've done a bit of reorganizing with your query and this version will pass, although it might not be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT E."ci", E."nombre"
FROM EMPLEADO E

INNER JOIN empleado ON "ci"= T."ciempleado"

where E."ci" IN (SELECT E."cisupervisor" FROM EMPLEADO E) and 

(SELECT E."nombre",E."apellido",P."nombreproy"
FROM EMPLEADO E, PROYECTO P
WHERE E."cisupervisor" IN (SELECT E."ci"
FROM EMPLEADO E, PROYECTO P, TRABAJAEN T
WHERE E."sexo"='F' AND E."ci"=T."ciempleado" AND T."horas">60 AND T."codproy"=P."codproy" AND P."fechaini"=2010
));
```